# Blank Heroku app throwing H14 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just created a blank Heroku app using command 'heroku create' and navigated to the address designated to the app.  The page read as follows:

> **Application Error**
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I checked the logs in the command line, and it said:

> 2014-07-03T17:02:42.854237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=**H14**
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=68df453d-11c7-4087-a10c-ce12e3117161 fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:02:43.933191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=2738adb7-65f6-40dd-b29f-0cbe2cbd60f3 fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:02:51.767010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=3b863dd5-ded8-462a-865f-6a39157ee414 fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:02:52.134163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=08f65bbe-3ab5-4cef-9154-8c8b3ced919e fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:03:04.942054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=21d8938b-2ed8-48ca-ba69-ef753759ee9e fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:03:05.325708+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=12f6ffa0-1d0a-4827-b3f3-1a6dad604177 fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:04:27.395593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=adb01b6b-2763-4270-ad0c-4b12f207c5c3 fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-07-03T17:04:27.882267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=aqueous-beach-3520.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=852edcba-a708-41ec-90e4-306366cf68d3 fwd="104.33.31.5"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

I've done a little bit of surfing, but most people seem to be encountering the H14 error after pushing.  I haven't done any of that yet.  I've also tried restarting heroku and scaling the dynos.  Help?

Edit:

Once I pushed an existing application to Heroku, this issue went away.  It looked like I could not deploy a blank Heroku application for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any application code yet!

You have to push application code with a Procfile that defines your processes.  You won't be able to scale your web dynos until that's done, because you don't have any web dyno processes defined.

If, as your tag suggests, you want to deploy a rails app specifically, try following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4).

Answer (score 4):

You need to scale your web dyno up from 0 to 1. You don't have one running at the moment. To do this go to heroku.com, click on your app, drag web dyno to one and click 'apply changes'! Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: I actually don't see anything to drag.  Under the "Dyno" section of the dashboard, it's completely empty.